# How to send text to other page? 'package:flutter/src/material/tab_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 181 pos 12: 'value >= 0

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

heelp me I want to send text from the first page to the second page.

**Firts Page**

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
              child: RaisedGradientButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Dapatkan Pengukuran',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontFamily: 'Nunito',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: const <Color>[Colors.purple, Colors.blue],
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ShowMeasurementsPage(                            
                              name: name.text,
                              nohap: nohap.text,
                            
                      ),
                 ),
         );
   }),
)
```

*Second Page**

and i want showing text this second page but error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShowMeasurementsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String tag = 'show-measurements-page';
  const ShowMeasurementsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ShowMeasurementsPageState createState() => _ShowMeasurementsPageState();
}

class _ShowMeasurementsPageState extends State<ShowMeasurementsPage> {
  final String? name, nohap;
  _ShowMeasurementsPageState({this.name, this.nohap});
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: you should use state management packages like getx or provider.. it will make everything easier and more stable for your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass the arguments to the StatefulWidget, then you can access them in the `build` method by using `widget.name`, or `widget.nohap`.

For example:

```dart
class ShowMeasurementsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String tag = 'show-measurements-page';
  final String? name;
  final String? nohap;

  const ShowMeasurementsPage({
    Key? key,
    this.name,
    this.nohap,
  }): super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ShowMeasurementsPage> createState() => 
    _ShowMeasurementsPageState();
}

class _ShowMeasurementsPageState extends State<ShowMeasurementsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        if (widget.name != null)
          Text(widget.name!),
        if (widget.nohap != null)
          Text(widget.nohap!),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. but im trying erro :Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/text_form_field.dart': Failed assertion: line 155 pos 15: 'initialValue == null || controller == null': is not true.)

Comment: Hmm, you might consider opening a new question for that - It doesn't seem to pertain to any of the code you've posted

Comment: sorry my mistake I forgot to remove initialValue: '',
Once again, thank you. Now it's running normally